# What city skyline is this picture of?

Tags: identify-this

[image]
So I stumbled upon a picture of a cityskape. I'd like to know what city is in the picture. Help anyone?

Answer (score 33):

This is Canary Wharf in London. The photo is taken from the south west of Canary Wharf, across the Thames or from a boat. [Here is a view from a similar location](https://goo.gl/maps/mHvWVqSHAkTQyDA58).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I excluded London by the sheer fact there was no Longon Eye in sight. Guessing that location really haunted my for quite a time. You, sir, made my day.

Comment: The Eye is quite a bit upstream from Canary Wharf.

Comment: Specifically, about 7km away.

Comment: London is a big place, and the London Eye isn't tall enough to be visible from far away.  It's iconic, and also near to other iconic landmarks such as the Houses Of Parliament.  But the Gherkin and the Walkie-Talkie and others in the City, the Shard on the south bank, and 1 Canada Square (with the shallow pointed roof in the middle of the picture) are recognisable from much further.